# Nested Dynamic SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I am Trying to write a dynamic SOQL Query with a nested query.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Books__c> filterRecords(String bookNumber, String PDCN, String Brand, String Type){
    System.debug('bookNumber__c->'+bookNumber__c);
    System.debug('PDCN->'+PDCN);
    System.debug('Brand->'+Brand);

    String query = 'SELECT Id,Content__c,ForecastWeekIndicator__c,Generic_PDCN__c,isExpired__c, '+
        'BrandStandardName__c,DPForecast_BaseUnits__c,ForecastStatus__c,Generic_DateTime__c, '+
        'Type__c,OperationalForecast_BaseUnits__c,PackageStandardName__c,bookNumber__c__c '+
        'FROM Books__c WHERE Type__c =:Type '+
        'AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Books__c FROM User_Specific_Books__c '+ 
        'WHERE Books_Delete__c = TRUE AND User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId())';
    if(string.isNotEmpty(bookNumber__c) && bookNumber__c!=null){
        query = query + ' AND bookNumber__c__c =: bookNumber__c';
    }
    if(string.isNotEmpty(PDCN) && PDCN != null){
        query = query + ' AND Generic_PDCN__c =: PDCN';
    }
    if(string.isNotEmpty(Brand) && Brand != null){
        query = query + ' AND BrandStandardName__c =: Brand';
    }
    System.debug('query--->'+query);
    List<Notification__c> lst;

    try{
        lst = Database.query(query);
        system.debug('List--->'+lst);

    }catch(Exception e){
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }

    if(!lst.isEmpty()){
        return lst;
    }
    else
        return null;
    }
}
```

and, I am getting exception ***expecting a right parentheses, found '('***. 
Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Thomas, If either answer below [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use actual Apex in dynamic queries. Only "simple" variables are allowed. The problem is in the following line.

```
    'WHERE Books_Delete__c = TRUE AND User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId())';
```

Assign the value to a variable first:

```
Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
...
    'WHERE Books_Delete__c = TRUE AND User__c = :userId)';
```

Comment: @ThomasPete you're welcome! P.S. String.isNotBlank also checks for null values, no need to check that separately in your code.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use dot reference in dynamic query. Here is your problem:

```
'WHERE Books_Delete__c = TRUE AND User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId())'
```

You need to add some context variable to store the `Id` and then change it to:

```
'WHERE Books_Delete__c = TRUE AND User__c = :runningUserId'
```

Comment: Thanks, Adding a context variable did it!